# convert date format while using date_add function in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm using the query below to add 14 days to a date

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(Paper_Sent_Dt,INTERVAL 14 DAY) as Rem_date from Referee_History;
```

the date format is yyyy/mm/dd but I require it in dd/mm/yyyy format.
Is it possible to convert the date format while using the DATE_ADD function??

as in, something like this

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE_ADD(Paper_Sent_Dt,INTERVAL 14 DAY),%d-%m-%y) as Rem_date from Referee_History
```

if yes, please tell me how
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, Can you try it?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('2014-06-06',INTERVAL 14 DAY), '%d/%m/%Y');
```

O/P

```
20/06/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be something lik:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Paper_Sent_Dt,INTERVAL 14 DAY),%d-%m-%y) as Rem_date  
FROM 
    Referee_History
```

To take it further, here is the article: http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format