# SQL: How to convert date key to yyyy-ww format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a variable (order_date_key) that is formatted as the number of days since January 1, 1990. For example, the number 42711 represents 2016-12-09, or the date that is 42,711 days since 1/1/1990. I converted that number to yyyy-mm-dd format using:

`SELECT DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', order_date_key) AS DateAdd`

I want another column that converts the date to yyyy-ww format. For example, 2022-05 would represent the 5th week of 2022. I tried using the following as a first step, but I received an error that 'Week' is an invalid function.

```
 SELECT *
  ,DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', order_date_key) AS DateAdd 
  ,WEEK(DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', order_date_key)) AS Week'
```

Sample data (days since 1900-01-01): 42734, 42711, 42720, 42760

Desired output (yyyy-ww): 2022-05, 2022-03, 2022-03, 2022-01

If you know how to do this in one step, that would also be helpful.

Comment: dateadd() and datepart()  ...  Your question is ambiguous, always best to supply sample data and desired results

Comment: This sounds like you need a calendar table.

Comment: The date functions you show here look like mysql but you tagged this with sql server. Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert date format while using date\_add function in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662140/convert-date-format-while-using-date-add-function-in-mysql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get week number from dates in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317547/get-week-number-from-dates-in-t-sql)

Answer (score -1):

Answered my own question thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662140/convert-date-format-while-using-date-add-function-in-mysql).

```
SELECT *
,DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', order_submission_date_key) AS DateAdd 
,DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('1900-01-01', order_submission_date_key), 'Y-u')
```